# Reading binary file with fstream

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, char, fstream

I am reading a binary file with fstream and storing the information in an array of characters:

```
int dataLength = 32;
int counter = 0;
char data[dataLength];
char PMTone[dataLength/4];
std::fstream *fs = new std::fstream(inputFileName,std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
fs->read((char *)&data, dataLength);
//of the 32 characters in data[], I need first, 5th etc elements:
//fill first pmt info
for(int i=0; i<(dataLength/4); i++){
PMTone[i]=data[counter];
counter+=4;
}
```

Now I'm setting PMTone[7] to be a as a test:

```
PMTone[7] = "a";
```

I get the error:

> mdfTree.cpp:92:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to
>   ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

I don't understand why the elements in PMTone[] are pointers to chars, when PMTone[] was defined as an array of chars.

When I do treat PMTone[] as an array of pointers to chars:

```
(*PMTone)[7] = "a";
```

I get another error that I don't understand:

> mdfTree.cpp:91:18: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array
>   subscript

This seems to imply that the compiler doesn't consider PMTone[] to be an array at all, but simply a pointer to char.

Can anyone shed light on what is happening here? Why has PMTone[] become an array of pointers to chars?

Answer (score 2):

The literal `"a"` is not a character.

You need:

```
PMTone[7] = 'a';
```

Answer (score 1):

`"a"` is not a character it is an array of characters, 'a' followed by a null terminator.

You would need

```
 PMTone[7] = 'a';
```

with single quote. Incidentally I am surprised that it compiles earlier because dataLength wasn't declared as const.

`PMTone` itself is of type `char[8]` which is an array of characters. However it decays to a pointer and `(*PMTone)` is the first element, of type `char`

Answer (score 0):

An array is a way of storing values by having the address of the first element and accessing other elements by index.
An array is basically a pointer to the first element.

When you create an array of `chars`

```
char arr[n];
```

program actually creates room for n characters in the memory.

When accessing `arr[0]` let's say like this:

```
arr[2] = 'a';
```

program is actually doing this:

```
*(arr + 2) = 'a';
```

meaning you are accessing a character which is stored 2 Bytes further from the memory location of the first element in the array (hence, the `arr + 2`), with the first element being `arr[0]`.
The address of the first element is `&(arr[0])` or, `arr`. Both are the same values.

The bug is where you tried saving a string `"a"` into a `char`.

The problem is you tried fixing it by dereferencing a dereferenced pointer:

```
(*PMTone)[7] = "a"; // is the same as
(PMTone[0])[7] = "a"; // when it should be 
PMTone[7] = 'a';
```